# php export csv i want to sum price column

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have table that has item,desc,price.
When i export as csv i want to sum the price column and put in the last row like sub total. csv generated fine.. i need to sum price column.

```
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $type . '-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.csv');
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');


     foreach ($price_list as $car) {
        $i++;
        $rows[$i][id] = $car->id;
        $text = $car->item;
        $rows[$i][des]=$car->des;
        $rows[$i][text] = preg_replace('/\s+/S', " ", $text);
        $rows[$i][price]=$car->price;
        $rows[$i][stocks]=$car->stocks;

        $rows[$i][edited_dt] = $car->edited_dt;


    }




    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
```

//query
select id,p_type,item,des,price,price_unit,stocks,stocks_unit,created_dt,created_by,edited_dt
                from price_list where state=1
                order by id desc

Comment: select id,p_type,item,des,price,price_unit,stocks,stocks_unit,created_dt,created_by,edited_dt
                from price_list where state=1              
                order by id desc

Comment: I gave an option below which uses rollup to compute the total price inside MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add sum in loop then add new column outside for loop which contain sum row

```
$price_sum = 0;
foreach ($price_list as $car) {
        $i++;
        $rows[$i][id] = $car->id;
        $text = $car->item;
        $rows[$i][des]=$car->des;
        $rows[$i][text] = preg_replace('/\s+/S', " ", $text);
        $rows[$i][price]=$car->price;
        $price_sum += $car->price;; //sum  price here
        $rows[$i][stocks]=$car->stocks;

        $rows[$i][edited_dt] = $car->edited_dt;


    }
  $i++;
       $rows[$i][id] = "";
        $rows[$i][des]="";
        $rows[$i][text] ="";
        $rows[$i][price]=$price_sum; //add sum here
        $rows[$i][stocks]="";
        $rows[$i][edited_dt] ="";




    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `$total = 0;` variable before the loop. Inside the loop, add `$total += $car->price;`. Then add the last row after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a pure MySQL solution to your problem, assuming you don't want to do any aggregation directly in your PHP code.  Consider the following query:

```
SELECT
    id, p_type, item, des, price, price_unit, stocks, stocks_unit, creat‌​ed_dt,
    created_by, edi‌​ted_dt,
    SUM(price) AS total_price
FROM price_list
WHERE state = 1
GROUP BY
    id, p_type, item, des, price, price_unit, stocks, stocks_unit, creat‌​ed_dt,
    created_by, edi‌​ted_dt
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
    (p_type IS NOT NULL AND item       IS NOT NULL AND des IS NOT NULL AND
     price  IS NOT NULL AND price_unit IS NOT NULL AND stocks IS NOT NULL AND
     stocks_unit IS NULL AND created_dt IS NULL AND created_by IS NOT NULL AND
     edited_dt IS NOT NULL) OR
     id IS NULL;
```

Simply iterate this result set, and when you hit the last record, simply access the `total_price` column which will be the sum of the price.  The marker for this record, besides that it is the last record in the result set, is that any of the columns *other* than `total_price` is `null`.

Here is a link to a simplified demo showing how this rollup trick over the entire table works:

## Demo